# Regex match lines with no more than a certain number of specific characters?

Tags: php, regex

This is my regex so far (assume PHP flavour):

`^(([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)){1,4}$`

And my test data:

```
U:\16. New Products\#Complete\Bottle Openers\20170210 St Patrick Bottle Openers\Small Lifestyles
U:\16. New Products\#Complete\Canvas
U:\16. New Products
```

The goal is to find all lines with no more than 4 slashes. In this example I expect to match the second and third lines, however when I test that in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uFbstY/1) it seems to match over multiple lines, despite having `multiline` set and using `^` and `$`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[^\\]` matches line breaks, use [`^(([^\\\n]+)\\([^\\\n]+)){1,4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/6Q9QJf/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh duh. Thanks. You should have posted that as an answer though.

Comment: Does it really work as intended?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does seem to, yes :)

Comment: Well, I guess https://regex101.com/r/6Q9QJf/2 can do a better job, but OK, let me post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, my regex backtracks horribly haha :P

Comment: You can even choose a better approach [`^(?:[^\\\v]*\\){1,4}[^\\\v]*+$`](https://regex101.com/r/DibsKl/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\\]` pattern is a negated character class that matches any char but a `\` char, and thus, it can match line breaks. To quickly fix the issue, you might add `\n` (and perhaps, `\r`) to the negated character class and use

```
^(([^\\\n\r]+)\\([^\\\n\r]+)){1,4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Q9QJf/4). The `[^\\\n\r]` cannot match CR and LF symbols and matches any char but a `\`, LF and CR chars.

A better regex  for this task would be

```
^[^\\\n\r]*(?:\\[^\\\n\r]*){0,4}$
```

Or, with the last quantified part set to possessive to enhance efficiency:

```
^[^\\\n\r]*(?:\\[^\\\n\r]*){0,4}+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Q9QJf/4).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\\\n\r]*` - zero or more chars other than `\`, LF and CR
- `(?:\\[^\\\n\r]*){0,4}` - 0 to 4 occurrences of

  - `\\` - a `\` char
  - `[^\\\n\r]*` - zero or more chars other than `\`, LF and CR
- `$` - end of string.